# angular creating a directive interacting with controller and service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm in the midst of refactoring. I have a service "myservice" called by my controller which basically makes a get request populates a $scope variable with reorganize data.

I'd like to be able to create a directive for my widget that I inject the service into but I'm unsure on how to organize my code. I'd like to be able to call the service from within my controller using the attributes defined in my directive.

I want my directive to look like so..

```
<mywidget service="MyService" server="http://localhost:8080/" api="abcservice"/>
```

My Service currently looks like so ...

```
 .service('MyService',function($http, $q){
  return{

        getPageData: function(server,api){
            //Creating a deferred object
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            //Calling Web API to fetch data - this is just hacky right now
            $http.get(server+api).success(function(data){
                //Passing data to deferred's resolve function on successful completion
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(){
                    //Sending a friendly error message in case of failure
                    deferred.reject("An error occured while fetching items");
                });

            //Returning the promise object
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
 }
```

Finally the controller ...How do I use the data that has been passed from the directive attribute ?

```
myapp.controller('MainCtrl',  function($scope, MyService) {   
     $scope.cleanData = function(res){
      // magical things happen including assigning some cleaned data to a controllers scope variable
    }    


    //not sure how to get server and api that i had in the directive
    MyService.getPageData(???????).then(function(res){
        $scope.cleanData(res);
    });

});
```

Comment: I understand sort of what you're getting at, but my first thought to solve this would be to make a function on the scope in the controller that takes two parameters.  Then you can just use ng-init to call the function with the right parameters from within the HTML.  I'm not sure if this is "The Angular Way" though since you wouldn't be able to test the controller without the view.

Comment: Have you tried using Restangular? It does what you appear to be trying to accomplish here.